# Mapping object properties from one array to another

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have two arrays (I'll call them `thing1` and `thing2`), of the same length, but with elements in different orders.

The elements can be matched up to each other based on the target and source names associated with each element.

Example matching elements from each are listed below:

```
thing1[0].target
Object {
  name: "Benthopelagics, large", parent: Object, imports: Array[7], TL: 3.717611213, B: 0.2…
}

thing1[0].source
Object {
  name: "Outside", parent: Object, imports: Array[4], TL: 5.149219037, B: 0…
}

thing2[216]
Object {source: "Benthopelagics, large", target: "Outside", value: 0.05800000596}
```

I'd like to copy the "value" field from thing2 to thing1, but being a newcomer to JavaScript, I haven't been able to figure out how to do the matching of source and target names.

Can someone give me an example of the syntax required?

Comment: Text slimmed down as requested.  The relevent code is really just the object structure I show above.  Can I set thing1[0].value = thing2[216].value programmatically, through comparison of thing1.target/source.name vs. thing2.target/source?

Comment: Well, that was much simpler than I thought it would be... with all the fancy remapping and whatnot I've seen in d3 examples, I completely overlooked that simple loops could do the job.  Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Loop through thing2. For each iteration of thing2 loop through thing1 and search for matching object properties.

([Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/humbleRumble/sxxgt4Lp/2/))

```js
for(var i = 0, j = thing2.length; i < j; i++) {
    for(var k = 0, l = thing1.length; k < l; k++) {
        if( thing1[k].source.name == thing2[i].source &&
            thing1[k].target.name == thing2[i].target) {
            thing1[k].value = thing2[i].value;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Just for contrast, here is a more functional programing type of approach...

```
    thing1.forEach(function (d1, i1, a1) {
       var res = thing2.filter(function (d2, i2, a2) {
        return d1.source.name === d2.source && d1.target.name === d2.target
       });
       d1.value = res.length ? res[0].value : null;
    })
```

Maybe the advantage of this approach is that it is more declarative in that you don't even have to think about managing the indexing.  All you do is declare the association rule and the built-ins manage the indexing details for you.  And it does have the additional feature of finalising the failed search cases.

Comment: I accepted the other answer only because it solved the problem first, and I'll need to take some time to study and understand the functional programming approach.  For others looking to solve this same problem, this may well be the superior approach.